# Vim latex on iPad pro

Tags: vim-latex, ipad

I want to use vim on iPad pro to write LaTeX (I never wrote it before in vim), but I don’t understand how to install LaTeX in vim on iPad. Саn someone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: While LaTeX with vim is great, you may be interested in mathjax enabled LaTeX in [Editorial,](http://omz-software.com/editorial/) which is able to provide a live preview.

Also, if you have a linux/unix machine, I recommend that you stick to that for LaTeX, because it can be far more powerful than any iPad/tablet. See [here.](https://castel.dev/)

---

You can use iVim from the AppStore, and install the plugins for editing, but that
will only allow you to edit your files. See here for the [tutorials](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/9ki5g8/ivim_ios_howtos/). Compilation however needs a LaTeX distribution, and currently there is no simple and cheap solution get one on your iPad for such a use.

Check [this](https://michaelgoerz.net/notes/editing-latex-on-the-ipad-with-ivim.html) for one way.

An alternative is to get a LaTeX app from the AppStore, write in iVim, and setup
tools to make the app compile the file, but I am not sure how this could be set up. Maybe Apple shortcuts could help.